# Twenty Twelve entry meta data - change and move

Tags: post-meta, theme-twenty-twelve

I'm trying to fix with the twenty twelve meta data. I've started fixing and successfully managed to get the date under the title of the post. Please visit [my site](http://skiss.suplife.se/) to see.

1. One thing I want to do is to remove the footer meta data "This post was posted in..". And instead add:
   A."Comments: #number
   B. "Share this - with the icons inline with comments - Now we have it centered above the comments with the jetpack plugin.
2. Above the entry title i want do display which category the post is displayed in. So its displayed first with category, then title and last the time.
3. I also wants configure the time of the day in the time data. So it should be displayed like "16:45 | september 16, 2014"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use twentytwelve_entry_meta(); in the post loops that calls the date, category and adds that "This post was posted in" text itself, then you'll have to remove it and re-write from scratch.

1A: Comments and Number displayed, refer to the comments_number function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

```
<?php comments_number( 'No Comments', 'Comments: 1', 'Comments: %' ); ?>
```

1B: If this is coming from Jetpack, it will automatically place them for you. If you want to change where they appear, take a look at this topic: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/manually-inserting-share-buttons

2: To show the current category(ies) that your post is in, refer to the the_category function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

3: To change the format of the date, refer to the get_the_date function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date

```
<?php echo get_the_date('G:i | F jS, Y'); ?>
```

As well as the PHP manual for more date options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've managed to get the comments part of it and now i think it looks great! I got problem getting the catgory to display over the entry title and to get the time show "G:i | F jS, Y".

Comment: I've go in to the wp-includes and general-template.php and find three strings with get_the_time which one should I edit? And how to I get it to be a part of my child theme?

Comment: What file are you editing - I assumed if you were in TwentyTwelve, that you were editing content.php or one of the content-something files? There's no need to go into the wp-includes folder - it is bad practice to edit core files in WordPress, meaning any files outside the theme and outside the wp-content folder in general - whatever changes you make to these files will get overwritten the next time WordPress updates. As far as the date, the function should be get_the_date, not get_the_time. Let me know if you need a code example for what you're trying to achieve and I'll update my answer.